# Processing events on Dynamically Loaded User Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a number of pages that I need to Dynamically Load User Controls and process events on controls on them. I have included sample code below for a trivial example.

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Button ID="BtnLoadControl" runat="server" Text="Load Control 1" 
            onclick="BtnLoadControl_Click" /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="BntLoadControl2" runat="server" Text="Load Control 2" 
            onclick="BntLoadControl2_Click" />
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ControlArea" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Deafualt.aspx.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void BtnLoadControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control controlToAdd = Page.LoadControl("~/control1.ascx");
        this.ControlArea.Controls.Add(controlToAdd);
    }
    protected void BntLoadControl2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control controlToAdd = Page.LoadControl("~/control2.ascx");
        this.ControlArea.Controls.Add(controlToAdd);
    }
}
```

Control1.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="control1.ascx.cs" Inherits="control1" %>
<div style="border: 1px solid red;">Test Control
<br /><asp:Button runat="server" ID="testButton" Text="test" onclick="testButton_Click" /></div>
```

Control1.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class control1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Button Clicked on Control 1!");
    }
}
```

Control2.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Control2.ascx.cs" Inherits="Control2" %>
<div style="border: 1px solid red;">Test Control 2
<br /><asp:Button runat="server" ID="testButton2" Text="test me" 
        onclick="testButton2_Click"  /></div>
```

Control2.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Control2 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void testButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Button Clicked on Control 2!");
    }
}
```

This is a very trivial example to show what I would like to do. My actual control is more complex and has **several properties that I set for the control I load** as I load it (in the default.aspx.cs files event handler).

With this example what happens is when the button is clicked on one of the loaded controls, the page is re-loaded and the control is no longer there. How can I keep the control loaded as well as process any events that happen on the control?

Answer (score 3):

You're asking if you can keep the control loaded in the page?

You can't keep the control loaded in the page, because the *page* doesn't exist! It's recreated on every request. It's created from the markup (compiled or not), and from running any code in the CodeBehind. If you want your controls to be there after a PostBack, then you need to recreate them on the PostBack. If you want to process events on those controls, then you'll have to wire the controls to event handlers when you recreate them after PostBack. Then the events will fire.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I will need to recreate them on PostBack, but I have not found any good solutions for how to do that. Also, how do you wire the controls to event handlers when you recreate them?

Comment: Add them on PostBack the exact same way you did the first time. And, just like any control, you want to do: btnButton.Click += new EventHandler(btnButton_Click);